# Undefined method `product_path` after upgrade Rails 3.2 to 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Weel, im upgrading my application of Rails 3.2 to 4.0 today, and use Ruby 2.0, but after upgrade and adjust the things when i try enter im my website i get error

```
undefined method `product_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fa5ae0111d8>:0x007fa5abdd4a20>
```

im my routes have the product path here:

```
  resources :products,:only => [:show,:index] do 
    post :calc_ship
  end
```

and when i execute `rake routes`

```
              product_pt_br GET      /produtos/:id(.:format)                                 products#show {:locale=>"pt-BR"}
                 product_en GET      /en/products/:id(.:format)                              products#show {:locale=>"en"}
```

Before update running normal, i dont know what is this, seems very simple but I could not solve, please help me i thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the output of `rake routes` shows you that the name of the `product_url` method should be `product_pt_br_url` or `product_en_url`.

```
**product_pt_br**   GET      /produtos/:id(.:format)  
**product_en**      GET      /en/products/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: Oh, i use this gem `https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator`, and ever use the route normal and the gem translate to me, works this way but not of me changing each route being the gem is to do this for me.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know about this gem. Sorry :S